# Excluding a file in Azure Function from Azure Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

We have an Azure Function project that contains a specifically named file that makes local debugging much easier. However we do not want that file to ever be deployed to Azure.

The standard package and publish process explicitly knows about the file named `local.settings.json` so that file is never deployed.

Some online docs and posts say that you can include a file in your project called `.funcignore` that has the same syntax as `.gitignore`. In there you should be able to specify files you do not want packaged.

The file we have is called `local.funcdebugging.json` and has the file properties of

- Build Action: None
- Copy to Output Dir: Copy if newer

Our .funcignore file looks like this

```
## Files that should be ignored from Azure Deployment

# EasyAuth Debugging file
local.funcdebugging.json
```

Despite these  settings the debugging file still get's deployed. How can I prevent this file being part of the Azure Deployment?

Comment: Where are you seeing the file ? in the bin folder ?

Comment: When locally debugging it is in "\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\" but when it is deployed to Azure it is in "wwwroot"

Comment: if it's in you gitignore, and it's still being deployed, I think it means this file is already in the source code.

Comment: gitignore? I have not included it in gitignore as I don't want it excluded from my git repo. It is the Azure Deployment I want it excluded from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been unable to get .funcignore to work.

Our alternative solution is

1. Remove "local.funcdebugging.json" from repo
2. Add a markdown debugging readme that explains how to use a file called
   local.funcdebugging.json and include some sample content
3. Add a "local.funcdebugging.json" entry to .gitignore in case future
   debugging attempts don't get tidied up and it ends up being added to repo and therefore deployed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to publish a `.csproj`. It's possible to customize what's copied to the publish directory with the [`CopyToPublishDirectory` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exclude-files). That's the directory created by the `dotnet publish` command.

For example in our case, we don't want to publish our Typescript source code, only the generated javascript code. We use the following configuration:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot\src\**\*.*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  <Content Update="wwwroot\vendor\**\*.*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  <Content Update="Locales\**\*.*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

With this, the source files are copied to the output directory, so they're available during debugging, but they're not copied to the publish directory, and thus it's not included in the deployed package.